# Move TFS Databases to a new SQL server

Tags: tfs

Id like to confirm this with you.
We are upgrading our TFS 2017 environment to use SQL 2016 SP2 in preparation of the TFS 2018 upgrade.
Our SQL Team will do this using new hardware.

I currently already use DNS aliases in my connection strings to the databases.

Can you confirm this would be the steps in short?

- Run TfsServiceControl quiesce
- Migrate the database to the new server
- Update the DNS Aliases to point to the new host
- Run TfsServiceControl unquiesce

Should it be that simple ? or should i take other steps to ensure the application is aware of the SQL Upgrade ?

I was only able to find an old article about this subject
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2014/05/15/migrating-team-foundation-server-databases/

Comment: That should work. The safest way to be 100% certain is to **try it on a test instance**. You'll also need to use `tfsconfig` to update the connection strings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#remapdbs

Comment: Thanks, so why would i need to run the tfsconfig if my dns aliases will pick up the name change ?
Does TFSConfig also update permissions and such on the new SQL Server ?